# Magento "display price including tax" returning the exclusive of tax price

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, vat

I'm getting strange behaviour in my catalog and product view page with regards to the product price that is being displayed.

I have set up the tax rules to display all values in the configuration as "including tax" and for the most part this is all calculated properly. In the checkout page the product prices in the table are correct, and the price including/excluding tax in the totals table is correct as well. The price entered for the product has been entered as inclusive of tax.

I've also just noticed that a logged-out user sees ex-TAX and my logged in user is seeing tax inclusive prices. `0 NOT LOGGED IN` is part of the `Retail customer` group though, which is in the one and only tax rule that I have applied.

Comment: I doubt that $_product or $_item have anything to do with the issue as they will both pass product data just from different template contexts. Double check your tax rules and try dumping out Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),true,false); to check what values are being returned.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @paj I have updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a `*` rule for the default tax location postcode/zip. This was for some reason causing it to default to tax-free prices.

As for why my logged-in user could see tax-inclusive prices, well the default shipping address postcode was a valid tax-inclusive address (in this particular scenario certain postcodes are tax-free).